# Capitalize ibid first letter when prenote is present

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I use biblatex with verbose-trad2 style and when I make a reference with a prenote ended with a dot i'd like it to see displayed "Ibid" with first letter capitalized as it is the case when there is no prenote. The example bellow explains the difference :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please give us more informations: Which documentclass do you use, which packages related to bibliography, which relevant options?  Best would be a complete compilable code, a minimal working example (MWE). Don't forget to add two bib entries ...

Comment: Try `\footcite[Ipsum.\bibsentence][Lorem]{sigfridsson}`. `biblatex` does differentiate between abbreviation dots and full stops (sentence end dots). With the standard setting `\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1\isdot}` all `.`s in the pre-note are treated as abbreviation dots and thus do not trigger capitalisation (this is presumably because often a pre-note might read "Cf." or so). If you want a `.` to always be a full stop in the pre-note you can use `\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker. A `.` can have two meanings for `biblatex`. It is either a dot to signify abbreviations or a full stop (period) to indicate the end of a sentence.

A `.` is treated as a full stop by default; this behaviour can be reversed by issuing `\isdot`, then a preceding `.` is treated as an abbreviation dot.

In the `prenote` formatting (`biblatex.def`) we find

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1\isdot}
```

So all `.` in a pre-note are seen as abbreviation dots, which makes sense since a prenote often contains a short abbreviation such as "Cf." or just a short word such as "see", but rarely an entire sentence.

There are two solutions here.
One is a temporary solution in which you tell `biblatex` to capitalise the next word anyway

```
\footcite[Ipsum.\bibsentence][Lorem]{sigfridsson}
```

The second solution will globally switch the behaviour in prenotes to recognise `.` as full stops.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{#1}
```